# How to right shift elements in Navbar in Hilla frontend framework

Tags: css, reactjs, frontend, vaadin, hilla

I am building the frontend of my app with HIlla. I have an AppLayout component which has a nested HorizontalLayout component that holds elements. But all of them are left aligned.

I want some of them to be left-align and some to be right-align. I checked the Docs for HorizontalLayout component and implemented the suggestions. I tried <HorizontalLayout style={{ justifyContent: "end }} /> but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.